# How to make Hibernate @DynamicUpdate work with two updating threads?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

I'd like to use @DynamicUpdate on my @Entity because I have two threads that change different columns on the same row and, without dynamic query generation, all columns are written on each update and the second thread overwrites what was written by the first one.

Example:

```
@Entity Task has attributes A and B set to false.
- Thread 1 loads Task#1 from the database and starts some long operation outside transaction
- Thread 2 loads Task#1 from the database and sets A=true, then saves
> the database holds Task#1 with A=true and B=false
- Thread 1 sets B=true, then saves
> the database holds Task#1 with A=false (!!!) and B=true
I was expecting to have A=true but it was overwritten with the 
original value when Thread 1 saved
```

The problem is that just adding @DynamicUpdate on the @Entity doesn't change the query, which is still updating all columns.
**UPDATE**: I managed to make this work by annotating all the class hierarchy with @DynamicUpdate (not just the base class holding the attribute as I did before) but I still have problems (see below)

I'm using Spring Data JPA 1.10.2 with Spring 4.2.6 and Hibernate 5.1.0.
One thread is fetching the entity with a custom find on a JpaRepository, the other one with a findOne() on the same JpaRepository.
Both call save() on the JpaRepository at the end.
Only the JpaRepository is @Transactional, so the read and save operations occur in different transactions.

I also tried adding @SelectBeforeUpdate but it didn't make any difference.

Also, is there any documentation on how to use dynamic query generation? I only found two lines in the [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicUpdate.html) but nothing in the user guide.

Or maybe I should use a different approach altogether? Any workaround? I can only think of updating each column separately with native sql, but that would be sad.

**Update:**
Now I have dynamic updates, so that only changed columns are saved, in theory.
But in practice the column that is marked as changed on one thread gets stored by the second thread too!
This is what happens in more detail:

My Entity is called Task and has "id", "priority", "executionTime" and "foo" attributes.
It is subclassed twice: BigTask extends Task and HugeTask extends BigTask, but I'm using Task when handling instances.
All classes are annotated with @Entity and @DynamicUpdate.
In the "setPriority()" method I've added a debug line that prints the previous and new priority value.

Using the web console, I start a Task instance: a new async thread is started that loads the Task from the database and starts some long-running operation outside of the transaction.
While the task is running, I change its priority on the web console and save. I see the debug message "Priority changed from 10 to 20" and the database holds the new value. The update query logged by hibernate is

```
update Task set priority=? where id=?
```

which is correct and shows that @DynamicUpdate is working fine.
After a couple of minutes the async thread terminates its task, sets the executionTime and saves. The hibernate query is now

```
update Task set executionTime=?, priority=? where id=?
```

which is NOT as expected. @DynamicUpdate is being used (the "foo" attribute is not included in the query) but "priority" has apparently been marked as modified even if its setter hasn't been called. And it is never accessed directly in the code.

Looks quite weird to me: the Task instances used by the two threads are different (or the new priority would be set on both updates) but apparently the "dirty flag" is in common! Could that really be the case?

Comment: I am running in a very similar problem right now. Were you able to get around the issue or fix it?

Comment: No I gave up. I found an application-specific workaround. I don't remember well but I think I made sure that the same Entity instance was being used by all threads, using some kind of Factory pattern and Entity pool. So sad.

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is often remedied by using some form of [locking](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking) in order to avoid two threads from concurrently changing the same row.

In general terms, you typically have two approaches to locking: *optimistic* or *pessimistic*.

**Optimistic**
This type of locking involves the introduction of a specific field used by the persistence provider to determine at the time of update whether some other transaction has changed the entity since it was last read by the current thread.  If the persistence provider detects this is the case, it will throw an exception, allowing you to handle it.  In such cases, you may be able to re-read the entity state and reapply the necessary changes and attempt to save again or throw an exception of your own.

**Pessimistic**
This type of locking pushes the lock control downstream to the database where you apply row-level locks at the time thread 1 reads the data, preventing any other thread from being able to read the row until the first thread commits it's data.  While this may seem like what one wants on the surface, this approach often does not scale very well, particularly where there is high potential for multiple thread/transactions needing to access and manipulate the same rows in close proximity of time.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was too quick in describing my problem. The two threads aren't accessing the same row at the same time. They are working on the same Entity but access the database at different times. I'm updating my question with more details now.

Comment: Maybe I could solve the problem with transactions, as you suggest, but I feel that @DynamicUpdate should be the correct approach, if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Lost a night on this one.. Small piece of information for anyone that comes here ..

In my case, I have modified my app as to reload systematically the entities before update by using the plain findById() from JPARepository. This is specially important for threads that take time to complete, but work on a entity retrieved before the operation.

This can in theory still lead to lost update as in in the case the data is modified between the entity refresh and save. More info here:

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-prevent-optimisticlockexception-using-hibernate-versionless-optimistic-locking/

In the cases when lost updates are unacceptable I have added optimistic locking (based on version field) and rejected the modification from a thread that has loosable updates.

When this was not possible, I refreshed the object in the StaleStateException catch before saving again (needed this only once)